# Main.js & polyfills.js compiling incorrectly - Angular/.Net Core Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular

I have an Angular 7 project integrated with the .Net Core framework. Very rarely does this happen, but sometimes when I build the app files with 'ng build --watch', the main.js & polyfills.js files don't compile correctly. The part I don't get is why it's only happening to the main.js & polyfills.js files and not every generated file with the project.

Console errors in the browser dev tools:

polyfills.js: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

main.js: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

I compared a working 'dist' folder with the broken 'dist' folder, where the build files live and they looked drastically different for the two files. If I run another 'ng build', usually that will solve the issue and I'm good to go.

This isn't really an issue locally because I can just use the workaround, but my build and deploy will often fail because of this error. Any help is appreciated.

Here's what the files look like when they fail:

polyfills.js

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
//# sourceMappingURL=polyfills.js.map
```

main.js

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(function (err) { return console.error(err); });
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "client-src",
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/SA",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": [ "app/*" ],
      "@services/*": [ "app/services/*" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the tsconfig file

Comment: @TonyNgo Sure, please see updated post

Comment: Is look normal to me. Can you upload your code some where so I can take a look at